# AWS Device Farm: How to use parameters passed to 'schedule-run' in custom test environment

Tags: aws-device-farm

I'm using bitbucket pipelines to trigger test run in AWS device farm. While scheduling a test-run, I'm passing few parameters to device farm. I want to perform an API call (to update my build status in bitbucket) from my custom test environment spec using those parameters (passed while scheduling a test-run). I want to know how can I access those parameters in my custom test environment.

Schedule run command (where I'm passing the parameters at the end):

```sh
aws devicefarm schedule-run --project-arn ${DEVICE_FARM_PROJECT_ARN} --app-arn ${APP_ARN} --device-pool-arn ${ANDROID_DEVICEPOOL_ARN} --name "${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}" --test type="APPIUM_JAVA_TESTNG",testPackageArn=${TEST_ARN},testSpecArn=${DEVICE_FARM_TEST_SPEC_ARN}, parameters={KeyName1=string,KeyName2=string}
```

Example of my test spec file:

```yaml
version: 0.1

phases:
    install:
    commands:
        - command
    pre_test:
    commands:
        - command
    test:
    commands:
        - command to test
    post_test:
    commands:
        - command --> here I want to call bitbucket api to update my build status (using the parameters passed in 'schedule-run' command)

artifacts:
    - location
    - location
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, AWS Device Farm does not support passing environment variables on the `ScheduleRun` API to the custom environment test spec file. However, you can dynamically generate the test spec file (using some YAML library) whenever you need to add / update environment variables to it, then re-upload it to the service.